# Duplicate title and meta description on same url

Tags: url, duplicates, seo

I'm working through some issues on semrush and they've highlighted that I've got duplicate title and meta descriptions on the following URL types:

1. domain-home.com/
2. domain-home.com.

I don't know how the second url would've come about so I'm not sure how to fix it. I can't see anything in the htaccess that would've generated that . after the domain so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the reason was because the client had included a link to the home page in the text of one of their pages that had a full stop within the href.

This caused the issue for semrush.

Next time I'll think about whether or not the reason could be simple human error rather than some more complex reason.

Comment: You should delete your question since it's of no value to anyone else. Typos are close-able questions.

Comment: I'd disagree with that sentiment. For someone looking to understand why duplicate URLs are appearing in an SEO Report, this experience could be quite useful.